# How can I run `Date.getDay()` based on different timezone in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running `nodejs 14` and need to get the day of the week based on an input string. I am using `Date.getDay()` method to get the value but it doesn't respect the timezone.

Below input strings are valid format.

```
2020-07-03T20:00:00.000Z
2020-07-03T20:00:00.000+01.00
...
```

My nodejs is running in the timezone `+10:00`. So for above two cases,

```
> new Date('2021-07-03T20:00:00.000Z').getDay()
0
> new Date('2021-07-03T20:00:00.000+01:00').getDay()
0
```

it shows `Sunday` as the output which is in the timezone `+10:00`. How can I get the day of week based on the timezone specified in the input string? So in above case, I'd like to get value `6` which is Saturday.

I'd like to use build-in method rather than 3rd party library like momentjs which is too big.

Comment: `Date` has a method `toLocaleString()`, that might be what you need

Comment: `toLocaleString` only return a string represent the date. How can I get the day of week from that?

Comment: You can use [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) and specify a timeZone option. `new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-DE', { timeZone: 'Asia/Shanghai', weekday: 'long' }).format(date))`

Comment: for the method using `toLocaleString`, the returned string can be passed to `Date` again and the day can be obtained from that. Although @pilchard's method might be more convenient.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I get the timezone name from the string? The timezone in @pilchard's example is `Asia/Shanghai`. The string ends with an offset `+08:00`. How can I convert `+08:00` to `Asia/Shanghai`?

Comment: You can use the generic timezones `Etc/GMT+8` full list here: [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) or see [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) (this is why people use libraries)

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but here goes.

- `Date.getDay` returns day according to *local time*.
- `Date.getUTCDay` returns day according to *UTC*.

If you need to get the day number according to a *specific timezone* then you need to add the offset of that timezone and use `getUTCDay`.

I use [date-fns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns) and [date-fns-tz](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns-tz).

- `getTimezoneOffset` returns the `milliseconds` offset of the given timezone at a specific point in time. The second parameter is relevant for timezones that can shift offset with daylight savings
- `addMilliseconds` just adds the milliseconds to the date to make `UTC` appear with the same offset as you would like
- `getUTCDay` will then act like your timezone and return the day at the specific timezone

```js
import { addMilliseconds } from "date-fns";
import { getTimezoneOffset } from "date-fns-tz";

export const getDayNumber = (date: Date, timeZone: string) => {
  const offset = getTimezoneOffset(timeZone, date);
  return addMilliseconds(date, offset).getUTCDay();
};
```

And if you run your test with `TZ=UTC` environment variable option (or any other timezone) then the following should always pass. (I've kept in one test to keep concise and illustrate)

```js
// Your imports to go here for getDayNumber
  describe("getDayNumber", () => {
    it("returns correct day number at 'Australia/Sydney'", () => {
      expect(getDayNumber(new Date("2022-01-29T13:00:00.147Z"), "Australia/Sydney")).toBe(0);
      expect(getDayNumber(new Date("2022-01-30T00:00:00.147+11:00"), "Australia/Sydney")).toBe(0);

      expect(getDayNumber(new Date("2022-02-04T13:00:00.147Z"), "Australia/Sydney")).toBe(6);
      expect(getDayNumber(new Date("2022-02-05T00:00:00.147+11:00"), "Australia/Sydney")).toBe(6);

      expect(getDayNumber(new Date("2022-01-31T00:00:00.147+11:00"), "Australia/Sydney")).toBe(1);
      expect(getDayNumber(new Date("2022-01-31T23:59:59.147+11:00"), "Australia/Sydney")).toBe(1);
    });
  });
```